# Pine Script - expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

Tags: pine-script

Copied this from another script I wrote where it works. But cant see why it is not compiling

1:32:31 Compiling...

21:32:32    Error at 39:5 Extraneous input 'alertMsg' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

21:32:32    'SB' saved.

**_**

changed spacing to 4

// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// slippery

```
//@version=5indicator(title= "Street Bounce", overlay=true)
```

```
// Calculate the 8-bar and 20-bar Exponential Moving Average (EMA)fastAverage = ta.ema(close, 8)slowAverage = ta.ema(close, 20)price1 = input.price(defval = 0)
```

```
//plot
```

```
plot(fastAverage, color=color.yellow, title="Fast EMA")plot(slowAverage, color=color.blue, title="Slow EMA")
```

```
// check any condition you needed to firecheckForAlert()=>alertMsg = ""
```

```
//check for price cross of 20 EMA
cross1 = ta.crossover(input.price(defval=0), ta.ema(close, 20))
if (cross1)
    alertMsg += str.format("cross {0} for {1}!\\n", syminfo.ticker)

cross2 = ta.crossunder(input.price(defval=0), ta.ema(close, 20))
if (cross2)
    alertMsg += str.format("cross {0} for {1}!\\n", syminfo.ticker)
```

```
// Plot cross over point
plotshape(cross1 ? low : na, color=color.red, style=shape.triangleup, text = "BUY", textcolor = color.red,location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(cross2 ? high : na, color=color.green, style=shape.triangledown, text = "SELL", textcolor = color.green,location=location.abovebar)
```

```
//any other checks needed
```

```
    alertMsg
```

```
fireAlert(ticker, freq = alert.freq_once_per_bar)=>
    msg = request.security(ticker, timeframe.period, checkForAlert())
    if str.length(msg) > 0alert(msg, freq)
```

```
fireAlert("AUDUSD")
fireAlert("EURUSD")
fireAlert("GBPUSD")
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show us a code properly formatted. Your error comes from a mal formatted code, we can't help you with your code presented this way in StackOverflow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.